# Styling h1 tags nested in a div two levels deep - inheritance misunderstanding?

Tags: css, inheritance

Why are my h1 tags not styled, although they are simple descendant tags? Could you tell me, what I'm misunderstanding about inheritance in this case? The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SPN6M/1/).

HTML

```
<div id="title">
  <div class="left"
      <h1>Lala</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right"
      <h2>Lulu</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
}

#title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 64px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 60px;
    background: #000;
}

#title > .left {
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    width: 380px;
    background: #C2D;
}

#title > .right {
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    width: 124px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    background: #5CC;
}

h1 {
    color: #FF4;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to include relevant code samples in your question (note: you can edit your question), so that the question can stand on itself. Now, if your linked site is fixed or even (re)moved this question will not help future users...

Comment: Ah, ok, I read quite often that rather than pasting longish code, especially novices should provide an instantly modifyable sample a.k.a. a fiddle to facilitate help...

Comment: Well, a little bit of both is best: *do* post code, but try to keep it as short as possible so SO-visitors don't have to go through pages of irrelevant code. Which is exactly what you did in your edit, so that's great! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey now check to this

you forget to `disclose` `div`

Replace

this

```
<div id="title">
  <div class="left"
      <h1>Lala</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right"
      <h2>Lulu</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**into this**

```
<div id="title">
  <div class="left">
      <h1>Lala</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
      <h2>Lulu</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

`">"` at the end to close the `div`

Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/SPN6M/2/

Comment: Oh, thanks! That was quite some red eyed stupidity I produced there - back to HTML/CSS kindergarten I must go ;)

Answer (score 1):

In line 2 your code should read

```
  <div class="left">
```

Note the ">" at the end to close the div